# Print line and following text based on pattern matching

Tags: text-processing, perl

I am trying to filter lines from a text file based on patterns in proceeding lines which keeping the pattern matched line. I also need to rename the pattern matched files

for example:

```
>text chr1    
AAA  
BBA  
AAA  
>additional text chr2  
ABA  
AAA  
CCC  
TTT  
>some text chr3  
TTT  
CCC  
TCT  
>no good text 1 3  
AAA  
CCC  
TCT  
>unimportant text 2 3 3  
ACC  
CCC  
TCT
```

the command would print the lines containing "chr" and all following lines until a line beginning with ">" does not contain "chr":

```
>chr1  
AAA  
BBA  
AAA  
>chr2  
ABA  
AAA  
CCC  
TTT  
>chr3   
TTT  
CCC  
TCT
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, could you please [edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/483039/edit) to include additional context such as what you have tried. It also is not entirely clear what the patterns are. Could you please clarify? Thank you.

Comment: Does your data file actually contain those backslashes?

Comment: So you want to - deduplicate (`chr1`), and - remove integer numbers after `\>`?

Comment: I've made some edits: the "\" is a mistake. @RudiC I am not sure what you mean by "deduplicate," I changed the numbers to make it more clear they're just standing in for other unimportant text that I want to get rid of.

Comment: That output doesn't seem as if 'the command would print the lines containing "chr"' Where is the first "paragraph"  '>other text chr1  
AAA  
BBB  
CCC'?

Comment: @Rudi I don't understand what you're asking. The problem has two parts: (1.) I want to filter the text file to remove blocks of lines based on pattern matching in a "title" line. The title line to each block starts with a ">". (2.) The title lines should be edited to remove text except for "chr" and the following number

Comment: There are TWO title lines with "chr1" in the input, but just one in the output.

Comment: Sorry again - I made a mistake in an earlier edit. I've deleted one of the two chr1 sections. Hope this makes sense (I am finding formatting the questions a little confusing.) Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using awk, grep and sed. Assuming there aren't trailing whitespaces in the original file.

```
awk 'NR>1&&/>/{print ""}{printf " %s", $0}END{print ""}' file |grep chr|sed 's/^ //' |sed 's/^.*chr/>chr/' |awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\n";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

first, group blocks starting lines with '>' and preceding each field with a whitesapce

```
 >text chr1 AAA BBA AAA
 >additional text chr2 ABA AAA CCC TTT
 >some text chr3 TTT CCC TCT
 >no good text 1 3 AAA CCC TCT
 >unimportant text 2 3 3 ACC CCC TCT
```

second, filter oll tthe lines that contain the substring "chr"

```
 >text chr1 AAA BBA AAA
 >additional text chr2 ABA AAA CCC TTT
 >some text chr3 TTT CCC TCT
```

third, remove all leading whitespace

```
>text chr1 AAA BBA AAA
>additional text chr2 ABA AAA CCC TTT
>some text chr3 TTT CCC TCT
```

fourth, remove all characters between ">" and "chr"

```
>chr1 AAA BBA AAA
>chr2 ABA AAA CCC TTT
>chr3 TTT CCC TCT
```

and finally use awk to print all the lines with "\n" as output file separator

```
>chr1
AAA
BBA
AAA
>chr2
ABA
AAA
CCC
>chr3
TTT
CCC
TCT
```